# How to load `messages.properties` in java packages (Spring Boot)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-internationalization

I want to load multiple `messages.properties` files from the java packages.

I have a project setup like:

[image: Project structure]

And `AppConfig.java` is:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        final ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasenames(
            "file:./project/foo/messages.properties", // Not working
            "file:./project/bar/messages.properties"
        );

        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

But the above setup is not working.  How do I load multiple `messages.properties` from the java source package?  Is it even possible?

I just don't want to use the folder `src/main/resources` - I want to put the file `messages.properties` in each package folder.

Also, I'd like to rename the file like `ProjectFooMessage.properties` to match the filename (custom name).  Please enlighten me!

Note: I am using Spring Boot 2.1.14

Comment: In a normal Spring setup using Maven/Gradle, the `message.properties` file should be in `src/main/resources`, not `src/main/java`, in order to be on the classpath at runtime. You know, the same place you put `application.properties`. --- You should still put it in the `project/foo` subfolder.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I am aware of that - but I want to achieve my goal.  Do you know how?

Comment: since it is in src directory it is still part of class path . try messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");

Comment: @satyesht `classpath:` only looks for the files in `src/main/resources` - not working.. ;(

Comment: `classpath` looks in the classpath. Maven bij default only includes `.java` files from `src/main/java` all other types are going to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  I need to change `pom.xml`

```
// pom.xml
...
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.properties</include>
      </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
...
```

The key part is `<include>**/*.properties</include>` - so that I can include all `*.properties` files in the Java source folders.

Then, I can access the file with the below code:

```
...
messageSource.setBasename("classpath:project/foo/messages");
...
```

WOOHOO!

Comment: ALthough this works, you really should be placing those files in `src/main/resources`. YOu can just recreate the package/directory structure there and achieve the same without explicitly re-configuring the resource processing in maven.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the advice - I just really really want to have those files in the same package as the source code. That's all

Comment: If you recreate that package in `src/main/resources` it is in the same package.

Comment: @M.Deinum Isn't that requiring additional setup in Eclipse? Also, I'd like to keep the resource folder really simple. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate your time :)

Comment: No it doesn't require any additional work, it "just work (TM)" as that is the default for maven.